# LibreOffice distorts embedded videos

Tags: video, libreoffice, gstreamer

I'm using LibreOffice Impress on Arch Linux to make a presentation. When I embed a video into my presentation, the video initially plays fine, but gets distorted after a few seconds. The distortion seems to involve a combination of screen tearing, flickering, and other things. I read [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/shared/01/moviesound.html?DbPAR=SHARED#bm_id1907712) that LibreOffice requires `gstreamer` to play videos, so I have installed Arch's `gstreamer` package as well as all of the associated [plugins packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GStreamer#Installation). I also tried using different video formats and different codecs, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this problem by changing the `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN` environment variable in the file `/etc/profile.d/libreoffice-still.sh`. Originally, all lines in that file were uncommented, which I think made `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN` default to `gtk3`. I seemed to fix the problem by uncommenting the `export SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gen` line. Unfortunately this option makes the user interface not look as good, although it still seems to be functional.

**pre-2021 note**

This answer has been updated. Prior to 2021, one of the options in `/etc/profile.d/libreoffice-still.sh` was `export SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk`. That option made embedded videos play well and made the user interface look nice. However, this option is no longer available. I also tried adding it manually but it doesn't seem to have the same effect.

**references**:

- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/200288/impress-video-playback-mp4-flickering-ubuntu-18-19-lo-6/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LibreOffice#Theme